# make can't find files from GitHub action

Tags: makefile, github-actions

I'm adding GitHub action to my [repo](https://github.com/jcubic/fake-linux-terminal) that calls make. This is my Makefile:

```
CP=cp
TEST=test

all: build

image.z:
    ./make-image.js -d ./root -f image.z

build: image.z
    $(TEST) -d dist || mkdir ./dist
    $(CP) ./index.{html,js} ./dist
    $(CP) ./image.z ./dist
```

and got an error:

```
cp: cannot stat './index.{html,js}': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:11: build] Error 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

My makefile works locally.

This is my workflow file:

```yaml
name: Deploy
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 1
      - name: setup node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '17'
      - name: "deps"
        run: "npm ci"
      - name: "build"
        run: "make"
      - name: upload
        uses: betanzos/scp-upload@v1
        with:
          source: "./dist/*"
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
          recursive: 'true'
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          remote_dir: '~/websites/terminal/fake/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer on SuperUser [Bash extended globbing inside a Makefile](https://superuser.com/a/619851/50659)

It seems that the Make in GitHub action is using sh by default. Adding:

```sh
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

to Makefile solved the issue

Comment: All versions of make everywhere always use `/bin/sh` as the shell to run recipes: this is mandated by the POSIX standard for `make`.  Of course you can reset `SHELL` as you've done.  My preference is to write recipes that don't rely on bash features: that way my makefiles work on systems where bash is not installed.  YMMV.

Comment: @MadScientist my code works on Fedora out of the box without changing any settings. Maybe you have another explanation for why it works locally but fail on a GitHub action?

Comment: Yes.  It's because on Red Hat derived systems, `/bin/sh` is actually a symlink to `bash` so they are the same.  But on other systems (for example Debian-derived systems like Ubuntu and many container images), `/bin/sh` is not bash but a smaller, faster shell that implements only POSIX features (for example, `dash`).  So if you use bash features in your makefiles and only test them on RH-based systems it will work but if you take those same makefiles and test them on other distributions, it will fail.

Comment: This is basically due to a very bad decision taken by RH ages and ages ago, which they can no longer reverse as it would cause much breakage for their customers.  So, you have to work out the portability issues on your own (at least these days with containers its easy to check).

Comment: @MadScientist thanks for the explanation, Is there a way to use real `sh` on Fedora? And is there a way to make per Makefile setting that will force sh on RH-based system? It would be nice to have makefiles that work everywhere.

Comment: Well there's a discussion of this here: https://people.redhat.com/~thuth/blog/general/2021/04/27/portable-shell.html  As for how to get make to use that shell automatically, I don't know of a great way.  You can of course override the shell on the command line: `make SHELL=/bin/dash`.  You definitely don't want to replace your `/bin/sh` with `dash`: that will break your system.  Or you could switch to Debian or Ubuntu as your development OS of course! :)